# AttributeError: Generic detail view AddMessageView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Generic detail view AddMessageView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Basically I am trying to access a page for me to add post into a room through the link in room.html. However I received the error above. Why is this error happening??

It might be that i need to specify the 2 diff slugs in my classbased view but how do I do that if the slug belongs  to 2 different models?

url.py

```
    path('<slug:type1_slug>/<slug:type2_slug>/messages/', AddPostView.as_view(), name= "add_post"),
```

room.html

```
<a href="{% url 'add_post' type1_slug=room.slug type2_slug=category.slug %}">
```

views.py

```
def room_view(request, type1_slug, room_slug):
    context = {}
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=type1_slug)
    context['category'] = category
    room = get_object_or_404(Room, slug=room_slug, typeofcategories=category)
    context['room'] = room
    return render(request, "room.html", context)

class AddPostView(DetailView, FormView):
    model = Room 
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/add_post.html'
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)


class Room(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='typeofcategories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `slug_url_kwarg = 'some_slug'` to your class based view for changing the default slug attribute. For instance:

```
class AddPostView(DetailView, FormView):
    model = Room
    slug_url_kwarg = 'type2_slug' # or anything else based on your requirements
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/add_post.html'
```

Note that this slug is related to specific object from your model that you're looking for.

Comment: But now I have 2 slugs. Which means I will have2 lines of slug_url_kwarg?

Comment: But how do I link to the slug in another model?

Comment: You can not have two lines of slug url kwargs... One way is to override your `get_queryset` method in your `AddPostView` and filter your desired slug... for example write `return Room.objects.filter(categories__slug=self.kwargs['your_slug'])` in this way you can filter your object based on two slug... one of them in `slug_url_kwarg` and the other in your `queryset` method.